# sql stored procedure for data feed

Tags: sql, azure, sql-agent

I have a question on SQL DB running on Azure.

Can I have a timed procedure in Azure SQL that selects a value from a field in a .csv file and appends it to a table? I ask because I found this article that says Azure lacks the SQL Agent to facilitate this: https://www.cotega.com/docs/sql_azure_scheduled_job

I should just try it I know but I have not attempted to do this before and wanted to seek advice before taking a shot at it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Automation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/automation/) provides a great cloud-based alternative to SQL Agent. Please see [Azure Automation: Your SQL Agent in the Cloud](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/26/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/) and [Truncate table in SQL DB if DB is approaching max size](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-Automation-Your-SQL-30f8736b).